# It is impossible to get the Vox Populi badge

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I have voted 30 times today, which is the maximum. I have used my daily quota.

But for me, the Vox Populi badge shows the progress bar 30/40 — the badge is awarded after 40 votes all on one day. Is this a bug or am I missing something somewhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to vote more on questions, rather than answers. If you vote only on answers, you have 30 votes per day; each vote on a question (as long as you have five or more votes left) will increase that number by one, up to 40. There's a friendly reminder if you vote (what the system deems to be) too much on answers alone.

More details [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/90256/295232) on Meta Stack Exchange.

Comment: I think over a quarter of your votes should be on questions (which should be easy enough, given our ratio of 2.6).

Comment: @wizzwizz4 that’s a separate requirement for the Electorate badge, but it is effectively built-in to the Vox Populi badge — since answer votes are capped at 30, to get 40 you need at least 10 question votes, which is exactly a quarter.

Comment: Isn't this (& that MetaSE post) missing the ramifications/calculations on comment votes? My impression: Those count towards daily limits but not towards badges?

Comment: @LаngLаngС AFAIK comment upvotes are totally separate from other upvotes. There's no link between them mentioned in the [rate-limiting guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164899/295232).

Comment: Not mentioned is true. But: Can't be true. When one day voting not exclusively on comments, I still got the 'limit' reminders ("x votes left"). After comment voting limit reached no more regular post voting.  Guess the complete guide isn't as complete as claimed?

Comment: @LаngLаngС I just tried it, and even after reaching the comment vote limit I can still upvote posts.